# Overloading the function template

Tags: c++

How can I overload the `cb` function template so that the code will compile? Now the exception is:

```sh
error C2535: void notify_property <T> :: cb (const F &): member function already defined or declared
```

But the templates are different.

```
template <typename T>
class notify_property {
public:
    virtual ~notify_property() {}

    //1
    template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>>>>>
    void cb(const F& task)
    {
        set_cb([task]
            {
                try { task(); }
                catch (...) {}
            });
    }
    //2
    template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<T>>>>>
    void cb(const F& task)
    {
        set_cb([this, task]
            {
                try { task(_value); }
                catch (...) {}
            });
    }
    //3
    template <typename F, typename... A, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<A>...>>>>
    void cb(const F& task, const A &...args)
    {
        set_cb([this, task, args...]
            {
                try { task(_value, args...); }
                catch (...) {}
            });
    }

    virtual T& operator= (const T& f)
    {
        if (f != _value)
        {
            _value = f;
            if (_cb != nullptr) _cb();
        }
        return _value;
    }
    virtual const T& operator() () const { return _value; }
    virtual explicit operator const T& () const { return _value; }
    virtual T* operator->() { return &_value; }
protected:
    template <typename F>
    void set_cb(const F& cb) { _cb = std::function<void()>(cb); }
    std::function<void()> _cb = nullptr;
    T _value;
};
```

Аnswer:

```
//1
template <typename F, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>>>>* = nullptr>
        void cb(const F& task)
        {...}

        //2
        template <typename F, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<T>>>>* = nullptr>
        void cb(const F& task)
        {...}
```

Comment: Have you checked [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Notes)?  Your duplicate `typename =` parameters are not distinct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typename = std::enable_if_t` is problematic if duplicated because - as your error mentions - you're defining the **same function** multiple times, merely with a different *default parameter*.

Change every type template parameter

```
 // Type parameter, with a defaulted type
    typename = std::enable_if_t< ... >
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^ remove!
```

to a non-type template parameter that is part of the function's signature:

```
 // Value (pointer) parameter, with a defaulted value
    std::enable_if_t< ... >* = nullptr
 //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ add
```

(Or, as cppreference does it)

```
 // Value (bool) parameter, with a defaulted value
    std::enable_if_t< ..., bool> = true
 //                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is happening due to same parameters in function 1 and function 2.

The solution for this is pretty simple. Changing the parameters in one of the 2 functions works just fine. Just add a parameter on function 2 (or 1) of the type int. While calling it just pass 0 as an argument.
If it doesn't work then do comment down below :)

*(I don't have so much reputation yet so I can't comment. So I answered instead :) )*

Comment: Since it seems you're new to answering questions -- I suggest making your answers authoritative and based on concrete evidence, not worded as an opinion. People are more likely to upvote authoritative, confident, and well-researched/explained answers rather than personal and subjectively worded ones (even if the answer and content is the same). It also helps if you can provide code-snippets of the suggested changes, where applicable, so that it's easy to understand what is being recommended.